# Set X and Y of a view onclick not changing position

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-relativelayout

I am trying to programatically change the position of a `TextView`. I create the `TextView` in code and display it. Everything is working however the `TextView` stay in the top left corner of the screen regardless of and changes to `setX` or `setY` on it.

This is my code.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            textView.setText("Test");
            textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

            RelativeLayout Screen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.screenRelativeLayout);

            Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/shablagooital.ttf");
            textView.setTypeface(face);

            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int screenwidth = size.x;
            int screenheight = size.y;
            Random randdisp = new Random();

            int randscreenwidth = randdisp.nextInt(screenwidth) + 1;
            int randscreenheight = randdisp.nextInt(screenheight) + 1;

            textView.setX(200);
            textView.setY(200);

            Screen.addView(textView);
```

Thanks for your help.

Nicholas

Comment: you didn't given the same reference of the variable you have to give reference of it on click

Comment: @keyurLahani I don't understand what you mean?  The setX and setY values I put in there to test it is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LayoutParams`:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
params.setMargins(200, 200, 0, 0);
Screen.addView(textView, params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe set X and Y AFTER adding the TextView to the Screen.